# Google apps script application publish to google apps marketplace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

Can I publish google apps script application to google apps marketplace?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No you cant.
You can publish to the chrome web store. Look up the gas documentation its explained there.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: You can now do that officially: Follow this link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/domain-wide-web-app**

I think you can. (I haven't tested yet),...

Basically the "zip package" of a Google Script is conformed with two elements:

- An icon.
- A manifest file, which contents is this:

  ```
  {
      "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
  "name":"***NAME_OF_APP***",
  "description":"",
  "version":"10",
  "app":
      {
          "urls":["***URL_TO_PUBLISHED_WEBAPP***"], //Is like a normal WebApp, or it's something more than that?
          "launch":
          {
              "web_url":"***URL_TO_PUBLISHED_WEBAPP***"
          }
      },
  "icons":{"128":"script-icon.png"},"manifest_version":2
  ```

  }

So, you must set the Marketplace manifest tags ( api_console_project_id, container, something more?)...

I have my doubts about the last step of the publishing process (Fill out the Google Apps Marketplace Listing Review Request), beacuse it asks an screen capture video of your application demonstrating usage of OAuth 2.0 login and meaningful integration with Google APIs... I'ts already integrated in GAS, so i don't know what to do here about that ( and look if Google approves a GAS-made app or not).

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can, providing the web app Url
You only have to go through the whole manifesto thing