# Is it possible to publish a Google Apps Script Web App to G Suite Marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, google-apps-script-addon

I know it is possible to publish a Google Script Web App to Chrome Web Store, but it's possible to publish in  Google Suite Marketplace?

There's no "Publish to Marketplace" option in GAS editor, but I've looked at a Google Script-based apps manifest files from Chrome Web Store, and I think there's a possibility to do it.

Unfortunately, I have some troubles with the last step of publishing (filling out the Google G Suite Marketplace Listing Review Request) so I'm not sure if a Google Script-based app complies with the G Suite Marketplace requirements

In fact, a GAS manifest file from Chrome Web Store looks like this:

```
{
    "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    "name":"***NAME_OF_APP***",
    "description":"",
    "version":"10",
    "app":
        {
            "urls":["***URL_TO_PUBLISHED_WEBAPP***"], //Is like a normal WebApp, or it's something more than that?
            "launch":
            {
                "web_url":"***URL_TO_PUBLISHED_WEBAPP***"
            }
        },
    "icons":{"128":"script-icon.png"},"manifest_version":2
}
```

So, what do you think?

Comment: Related: [Issue in Web App publishing in Google Marketplace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56786137/1595451), [Google apps script application publish to google apps marketplace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21130661/1595451)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, now you can!

This feature became active not so long ago, but now you can publish Google Script Web Apps to G Suite Marketplace.
Google Developers website has a [good how-to instruction](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/gmail-publish-overview) on this topic.

Comment: Google implemented it a little late, but anyways, is possible now. Good to hear that for future projects. Thanks!