# Cannot publish apps to gsuite marketplace. “This form is only for specific addons”

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I spent 3 days to try publishing app in my sandbox gsuite domain. In the marketplace.

I'm trying to publish an app to my own domain. Whatever I'm doing I'm getting this error message

---

[image]

---

I followed the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing

and follow the instruction of all the guides.

I tried to publish using the chrome web store, I created a manifest, with and without project_id, whatever I'm doing I don't see the app in the "for your domain" section in the marketplace.

The only place I somehow success is when my using using Google Docs, and click "Add addon:", in the addons menu. They see my app, but not in the marketplace.

I have a specific question:
I'm trying to understand what this error message means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to publish a Google Apps Script Web App to G Suite Marketplace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261990/is-it-possible-to-publish-a-google-apps-script-web-app-to-g-suite-marketplace)

Answer (score 0):

The Publish tab is currently used only by Gmail add-ons, which do not require publishing to Chrome Web Store.
For the other add-ons it's required to have a Chrome Web Store listing.
The api_console_project_id is required in the manifest.