# Issue in Web App publishing in Google Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

I published my Apps Script Web App to the Google Apps Marketplace. After 5-7 days of reviewing, they shared a doc with Web App details with me and asked for a Test Account to test the App. But when I checked in console.cloud.google.com, it shows the Publish status as 'Unpublished (Rejected)'. Can't understand if the App has been rejected or still in 'under review'. Should I share the Test account details and wait or something else can be done? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, share it with the GSM review team and ask them about the publish status.

Comment: GSM review team will be a team specific to my app or it is something common to all apps?

Answer (score 1):

When the App needs updates, or if they need more information Google's Review team sets the status to Rejected. This allows you to make changes, or submit further information that they need. When the status is "under review" you are unable to submit the proper changes. It is strange but I would just submit the information and usually after all the changes are made or all the information is gathered they ask you to resubmit the App for review so they can click authorize.

Comment: Thanks for sharing some useful info.