# How to publish a Google Apps Script web app to the G-Suite Marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-apps-marketplace

First, I know there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261990/is-it-possible-to-publish-a-google-apps-script-web-app-to-google-apps-marketplac) but it is very old and that answer is not valid anymore.

I am working on a Google Apps Script web-app (either bounded to a Sheet, or a stand alone one that'll reference a Sheet). I am wondering if it is possible to publish it to the G-Suite Marketplace? All of the documentation I am finding talks about publishing add-ons and what not.

I saw [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/sunset#publish_to_chrome_web_store), and many articles/post link to it saying that is how, but it says publishing to the Chrome store is deprecated.

But I can't find anything on publishing a GAS web-app to the marketplace. Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to publish a Google Apps Script Web App to G Suite Marketplace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261990/is-it-possible-to-publish-a-google-apps-script-web-app-to-g-suite-marketplace)

Comment: @Rubén The other question was asked 5 years ago and the answer it had was correct at that time but was no longer valid. It didn't make sense to post a bounty on an answered question that wasn't valid anymore. And I also said in my post I am aware of that other question but that it wasn't applicable anymore. It felt more appropriate to post a new question.

Comment: @Rubén The updated answer is talking about publishing add-ons. I'm asking about posting a web-app, not an add-on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: **No**

I know this hasn't been explicitly written anywhere but I'm taking my cues from the following docs -

1. [Choosing where to publish](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-overview) - here they describe what can and cannot be published on G Suite Marketplace (albeit, Web Apps show-up nowhere)

[image: Choosing where to publish]

2. G Suite Marketplace SDK > Configuring the Marketplace SDK > [Extensions](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/sdk#extensions) - here too, they haven't listed Web Apps as a form of accessibility

[image: Extensions]

Hope this helps! Plus, I've built a fair amount of web apps myself and have always wanted to get it listed somewhere but haven't been able to do so - yet :)

Comment: Thanks! How do you make your web apps available for others? I suspect I could package it as a Sheets add-on. Or leave it as a stand-alone project file that folks can copy and publish themselves.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan - so, this depends on the kind of web-app; if its to be restricted to a domain, then that gets handled by `Session.getEffectiveUser()` or activeUser or I write pattern matching for domain names. Alternately, if it's to be accessed by all (even anonymous), I just leave them as is; some of the web apps I've written about can be found here - https://script.gs/tag/web-app/

Comment: Humm. My thought is to write a web-app that solves some problem and I want folks to be able to "get a copy" and publish their own. Trying to find a good solution for how to manage that.